# Is it bad to store temporary data into hidden element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

At one interview, once I attended, I was asked to create one java script based functionality in which I was said to create one form (say i.e first name, last name, email, age) and one listing(actually listing was kind of another form storing multiple entries) below this form. On submitting this form one new row was added to listing. However it is possible to remove any previously added listing row. and after adding removing, finally need to store this final state of listing. ( Kind of form post and server side scripting comes into picture )

So what I did that, On Form submit, adding a new `<tr>` row in listing table at the same time I serialized all form data except submit button using jQuery serialize and stored it in one hidden element of listing form.

On removing listing row, I was removing `<tr>` row along with respective hidden element for the same row.

All was working like great without any error. But the interviewer asked me that "The approach I used (hidden elements) was really proper?".

I replied, I could have used json? 
but Could not crack interview. 
So I want to know what is best approach that We can use to store data in such conditions?

Comment: Could it not be stored in an array? I mean instead of the hidden elements you store the values in an array.

Comment: The interviewer might just wanted to see your reaction when he/she criticises you.

Comment: I did all that just in 30 minutes, And even on his criticize, I was confident for what I did. Actually where I applied was one well known IT company.

Comment: I really don't understand SO sometimes. This is too localized and not constructive. This is a `code review` at best, and certainly not worth the 19 points.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, you are true. But when all these happened to me, my confidence went down. So wanted to know best approach. And it I am not wrong, SO is also where you can get best approach.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I just want no one to repeat the mistake if I did any so... hope you aer agree.

Comment: As it closed by sake of code review, just want to tell i strictly follow code indentation and web standards considering php, html, javascript and even in CSS. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach for client-side is to keep a list of objects separately and only store the reference to each item inside a property of your DOM element. This approach is very similar to what jQuery's [`$.fn.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) provides and has these advantages:

1. You don't have to serialize anything, the data stays in its native format; it should be said that you could have achieved this by adding a property as well.
2. All your data is kept in one place instead of scattered around in the DOM.

This is an example implementation:

```
(function(ns) {

var entries = {},
entryId = 1;

ns.Entries = {
   addEntry: function(data) {
     entries[entryId] = data;
     return entryId++;
   },
   getEntryById: function(id) {
     return entries[id] || null;
   }
};

}(this));
```

Calling `Entries.addEntry` returns an identifier that you can store in one of the DOM element's properties:

```
tr.entryId = Entries.addEntry(data);
```

Later you can use that `entryId` property to find the corresponding data in the entry list and use it.

```
var data = Entries.getEntryById(tr.entryId);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/arucuj/1/)

Of course, this particular functionality can also be solved server-side by using sessions.

Comment: jack. I slowly getting what you want to say but for more understanding, want to see it working. Please check demo link, its not working for me.

Comment: @RajanRawal The page is empty, you should look at the console or switch to edit mode; http://jsbin.com/arucuj/1/edit

Comment: is it known as wrapper, what have you done?

Comment: @RajanRawal Are you talking about the way I wrote the code? I'm using a closure to encapsulate the actual storage, so that you can only reference the data via the functions I've exposed under `Entries`.

Comment: I thoroughly got those two points you mentioned. I have never used such sophisticated way. Can you please do some little more coding in demo link. Please...

Comment: @RajanRawal If there's something you don't understand you can ask me, but don't ask for more coding because I wouldn't know what else to code :)

Comment: I personally liked this answer so much and mentioning `jQuery.fn.data()` was beautiful.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to HTML5, we now have the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements. These new custom data attributes consist of two parts:

- **Attribute Name**
  The data attribute name must be at least one character long and must be prefixed with 'data-'. It should not contain any uppercase letters.
- **Attribute Value**
  The attribute value can be any string.

Using this syntax, we can add application data to our markup as shown below:

```
<ul id="vegetable-seeds">
  <li data-spacing="10cm" data-sowing-time="March to June">Carrots</li>
  <li data-spacing="30cm" data-sowing-time="February to March">Celery</li>
  <li data-spacing="3cm" data-sowing-time="March to September">Radishes</li>
</ul>
```

We can now use this stored data in our site’s JavaScript to create a richer, more engaging user experience. Imagine that when a user clicks on a vegetable a new layer opens up in the browser displaying the additional seed spacing and sowing instructions. Thanks to the data- attributes we’ve added to our `<li>` elements, we can now display this information instantly without having to worry about making any Ajax calls and without having to make any server-side database queries.

source: [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

There are other methods too I believe.

Comment: dont have used html5 yet so just shake of my knowledge, would this tag work for all browser?

Comment: It's important to note that the attributes of elements don't effect the way that the browsers render the elements. IE even has non-standard HTML 4 attributes in use. Leveraging the `data` property should not be an issue regardless of browser.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy However, there's a distinct difference in how those attributes can be accessed; `.dataset.xxx` vs `.getAttribute('data-xxx')`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually instead of using hidden elements , you can add data to the html elements using jQuery. This is a better approach to make your data a little less obvious/direct to the users. Check the data() in jQuery.

Comment: Tamper-proof? How so?

Comment: what is temper-proof? I dont know that. Please explain

Comment: You can store values to custom named variables.SO on the first look you do not directly get the variables being used that is not the case with the hidden elements which makes it more than obvious.

Comment: Nothing client-side is tamper-proof.

Comment: Ohk ...may I say much harder to tamper with.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, I would say no.

Comment: I would also say no. You need developer tools to fiddle with hidden fields, and those tools also give you access to most other things.

Comment: All i meant as that it becomes hidden from plain sight and thus a little more secure.. I guess i need to be really exact with what I write .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with storing data client-side if the user can be trusted with it and nothing terrible happens to your system when he messes with it.

Only problem I can see with using hidden fields (or cookies) is that they get sent with every request, which might waste bandwidth. Not sure if that applies to your case, probably not, because you say you just submit once when all is done.

Comment: Then should I consider that, interviewer was expecting me to implement exactly what was there in his mind and that I did not do so he rejected.

Comment: Maybe. That's a common problem. Or maybe he just wanted you to defend/explain your approach (which you should be able to do).

Comment: I was not informed regarding maintaining data on page refresh. is it possible to maintain such data even on page refresh just by javascript?

Comment: `localStorage` is something to know about.

Comment: if I am not wrong then it was just introduced in HTML5. Right Sir?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with solutions that 'just work' is that they are not abstract enough and therefore tend to cause problems in the future. Consider your example; should you decide to store the temporary data in Local Storage (to allow users close their browser and return to it later), you'd have to rewrite how you store your data. If you stored it in a variable, you'd be able to add 'Save to Local Storage' just as easily as 'Submit to server' or 'Pass to Any Other Function' functionality. Your 'hidden element' approach would have to be rewritten for any purpose except posting to service.

Comment: Rewriting things later if a new requirement comes up is not a always a problem. There is merit in keeping things simple. No need to do more than necessary for the task at hand, especially if that would introduce complexity.

Comment: Hello Brian, i would favor @Thilo here as because i could have think about the points you mentioned but considering just interview and limited time, I did so.

Comment: Yes, you did so... and failed :/

Answer (score 0):

To start with, multiple forms on one page are wrong - it's data loss antipattern. The correct approach would be to place everything into one form. This way, it would work even without JS and you could use JS only to improve usability, not to provide basic functionality. This solution would degrade gracefully an it would be easy to debug and maintain.

Of course, saving the data in hidden field is a valid technique.

Comment: Agree with data loss antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

By writing submitted data into the form itself, and reading again from it, you've tied these two elements together - they are said to be tightly coupled.

What word happen if another requirement came through to displaye previously submitted data in the table also? Or to put the form on a separate page?

If you take a more MVC approach, you can separate out the logic for the various parts - reading, writing and sending data. For example, as you said, writing and reading from a JSON model. This would make each aspect more readily extensible in the future.

Comment: One could also argue that keeping all state for the form in the client before it is complete, makes for a nicely separated "view" component in MVC.

Comment: Actually I used twp separate form. One for main entry and another one inside which I showed listing and added those hidden elements

Comment: @Thilo, definitely agree that there's nothing wrong with modelling data on the client-side for a JS application. Maybe it's the way I read the original question, but it sounded like the way the data was being modelled was based on the original submitted form rather than what makes most sense for a data structure. Hard to comment with certainty without more details on the interview though

Answer (score 0):

I will not answer your question directly but will focus on interview and method you chose.

I would say you chose wrong way and well known IT company you applied this solution for can have problems.

You chose the way to store everything on client's side, but you shouldn't! As your client can lose a lot of data this way, because imagine the case when your listing form will never be sent? User will just forget to hit send (never trust user!). Then you lose everything... whole progress of your work... and let's say you've already added 50 listing items...

Also adding items like this can easily make your session expired (no requests to the server) and no data will be saved, because user will have to log in again. And you will have to handle it as well, or you will lose everything!

Sorry for exclamation marks, but I think data is crucial (especially for your client) so do not ever offer solutions which can make client losing it somehow.

So:

It's not bad to store data in HTML elements, but you need to apply this solution very carefully.

Comment: Carlos, I really learned new things from your answer but It was mandatory just to use javascript and not using any server side scripting. If allowed, then I could have send ajax, stored it in database and then only listing. Hope that was correct.

Comment: Ok - from your question I don't see any requirement, that you couldn't make ajax calls during the process. But if it's true, then I wouldn't work for them, as it seems they are ignorants in this case. Any data stored only on client's side can be tampered (it's in other answers). So the way you store it there doesn't really matter, as far as you can get it back. Then your answer was good, as it was working well.